# How to have a content div span the remainder height of a page without scroll?

Tags: html, layout, css

I'm trying to create a page that takes 100% of the height of the page, without displaying a scroll bar. However, I wanted to add a header above this, and when I do, a scroll bar appears due to extra height. I've tried compensating with a negative bottom margin to compensate for the extra length, but this doesn't seem to change the length. How can I prevent a scroll bar from appearing with this layout?

Here is the code I have:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  * { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  div#header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
  }
  div#content {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    Test Content
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I did try a margin-top: -50px with a padding-top: 50px on the content div before. However it doesn't behave as I expected, as the content will overlap the header even if I set a z-index.

Comment: The content div isn't being stretched at all, at least not in Chrome. What browsers are you working with?

Comment: Depending on your application for this, you could just add `overflow: hidden` to the body.

Comment: have you try setting <body> to 100% and assign a percentage height to your header and content?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc The content div stretches to the bottom of the page for me, I'm on Chrome 13.0 on OSX.

Comment: @ngen I need a scroll however if the content div is longer than the height.

Comment: @KMC I want the header to be a fixed height, and the content to be fluid based on content.

Comment: So you want to #content to have a minimum height of 100% window height - header 50px?

Comment: @ngen Right, but if the content is less than the height, I don't want a scroll bar to show up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way

http://jsfiddle.net/b27e8/

```
  * { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  div#header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
  }
  div#content {
    background-color: yellow;
    top:50px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your problem using:

```
div#header {
background-color: red;
height: 10%;  }
div#content {
background-color: yellow;
height: 90%;
margin-bottom: -50px;   }
```

You might have to play with the %'s to fix that...

**Edit:** I used Firefox 6 to test that, BTW.  You can get exact percentages too, using decimals (eg, `95.6%`

Comment: I don't want the header to be a fluid height, I'd like for it to be a fixed height, and have the content fill the rest of the page depending on browser length.

Comment: Oh, I see...sorry about that!

Comment: Could you use javascript? Using `window.screen.availHeight`, and then subtracting your header height, you could set the content to be that height..? Or is javascript off-limits?

Comment: I could, but it feels somewhat hacky since it seems like there should be a clean css solution for this. But I might have to resort to it if I can't figure it out, I'll keep it in mind though.